# Multi Resolution UI framework for Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I am developing an starling mobile air application.

I want to target Android and IOS devices.

I am searching for a UI frame work for starling mobile air application which give responsiveness just like in HTML responsive web site / web app.

I have googled a lot for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Feathers?

Comment: not yet. Thanks for your replay. enlighten me !

Comment: http://feathersui.com/

Comment: that's just plain lazy... http://bit.ly/16XfuVN

Comment: Starling framework is your answer to UI work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Gazman SDK](http://gazman-sdk.com). Its basically what your are looking for.